# how do get all parent of curent category in magento2?

Tags: magento2, category, menu

ex: I have category list as follows:
    Men
--top
---shoes
--bottom
I have current_category is **shoes**. so how to add class to this and all parent of this.

Comment: what you want to do for category, have you want  current category's all parent category id?

Answer (score 5):

Using below code you can get parents of current category

```
<?php 
  /* $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View */
foreach ($block->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
    echo $parent->getId();
}
?>
```

Comment: This code for category is working and is bringing all the categories of that product but if i want to target the **Men** CategoryID only. how to do that. Not other subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

Create Block and extended \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View

For Example

```
namespace Companyname\Categorylist\Block\Category;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, 
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory  $categoryFactory,
        array $data = array()) 
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper,$data);
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
     }

    public function getCategoryList()
    {
      $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
      $collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
              ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
              ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());
      return $collection;

    }
```